# Spring data couchbase querydsl integration

Tags: spring, spring-data, querydsl, spring-data-couchbase

Does `spring-data-couchbase` have support for integrating `querydsl` in the repository classes? If so can someone help me on this?

[This documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl)  does not provide me with the details on the `annotation processor` and `maven goals` to be used.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you more relevant way

- Yes, we can integrate **spring Data Repository** with **querydsl**.
- I have no much more idea with Couchbase but here i try to resolve your issue.
- Not require any necessary xml or annotation to configure Querydsl but some rules to follow to configure Querydsl with Repository.
- Add the required libraries for Querydsl; querydsl has been coming with a lot of libraries for serving the different kinds of persistence stores. Libraries such as **querydsl-core**, **querydsl-apt** and **querydsl-jpa** are the required libraries, cause we are going to use the Querydsl with the JPA.
- Compulsory to  extension Repository by extending the **QueryDslPredicateExecutor**, that's generic interface has given the developer ability to provide it the entity that it being processed in its query.

1) Here I attached pom.xml file

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
     <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.2</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
     <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.2</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
     <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.2</version>
     </dependency>
```

2) Extended the Repository class with QueryDslPredicateExecutor

```
@Repository

 public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer>,QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Employee>{
```

public Employee findByEmployeeId(Integer id);
 }

[Click here for relevant configuration](http://[1]:%20https://www.hascode.com/2014/02/creating-elegant-typesafe-queries-for-jpa-mongodbmorphia-and-lucene-using-querydsl/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can integrate spring Data Repository  with querydsl.

Its do have support of integrating with repository classes.

for mvn Goals - generating and for Annotation processor

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

for more specific info 
look more into this blog https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: You did not answer the question at all.

Comment: kindly go through the blog which i have attached.

Comment: Spring data do have support.

Comment: @JesusTheHun Couchbase repository is also a Data Repository so even QueryDsl implementation applies.

Comment: @JesusTheHun I gave the information about AnnotationProcessor and maven goal conf

Comment: Spring Data Couchbase is totally different from the regular Spring Data, so no it does not apply.

Comment: Ohh I see. I will try can check it out. and update the answer:)

Comment: @JesusTheHun https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-couchbase. my understanding is that couchbase repository is the extension of data repository.

Comment: @JesusTheHun can you add references in what way couchbase repository different from data repository